# Why does my python function not return any of my conditions, other than None?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, range

I'm working on making a simple RPG battle system, with this function to decide what types of attacks the player will use.  But I have had no luck getting my conditionals to return their designated string.  All it ever returns is the word "None".

By the way I just started learning programming about a month ago, so I don't know very much about Python.

```
def attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed():
    #Random number generated from a range and then placed into a list.
    import random
    number_list = [random.randrange(1, 105)]
    print(number_list)
    print("")
    #Check list to see where my generated number gets put. 
    #Big Chance For Regular Attack
    range1 = []
    n = range(1, 76)
    for n in n:
        range1.append(n)
    if range1 in number_list:
        return "normal_attack"
    #Small Chance For A Critical Attack
    range2 = []
    j = range(76, 101)
    for j in j:
        range2.append(j)
    if range2 in number_list:
        return "critical_attack"
    #Tiny Chance For The Attack To Miss
    range3 = []
    v = range(101, 106)
    for v in v:
        range3.append(v)
    if range3 in number_list:
        return "missed_attack"

print(attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed())
```

Comment: When you say *it* returns `None` what does? How are you calling this? Is this really your whitespace?

Comment: That's... terrible. Consider using chained conditions instead.

Comment: You really shouldn't do `for n in n`, it is horribly confusing. (For future readers, the `n` created by `for` loop overrides the previous one).

Comment: Especially as all the for loop does is take the elements provided by the `range` and add them to another, empty, list. Argh.

Comment: @doctorlove When i use print at the bottom, it returns the word None.

Comment: Sorry @bo2006 - I couldn't see that til the code in the question got editted.

Comment: I didn't see this mentioned anywhere, but the import statement should be at the top of your file, for style and readability. [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: @plg Even if i move the function to another file using a module?  I did it for redundancy cause of the scope thing.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have never heard of chained conditions before, also I know my code is terrible.  like i side I just started programming(no prior experience with any code language).

Comment: @bo2006 if you move the function to another file, move the import with it. Also you should read a bit more about scopes as you don't seem to quite get how they work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the point of `in`.

Let's take the 3rd part: you have a `range3` which is filled in a quite weird way. Then you check if this list is contained in `number_list`, which contains only one element, a number.

So this condition is probably never fulfilled.

What you probably mean is

```
randnum = random.randrange(1, 105) # no list, directly the number.

if randnum < 76:
    return "normal_attack"
elif randnum < 101:
    return "critical_attack"
else:
    return "missed_attack"
```

Answer (score 5):

**Try this simplified version of your code:**

```
def attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed():
    import random
    roll = random.randrange(1, 105)
    if roll in range(1, 76):
        return "normal_attack"
    elif roll in range(76, 101):
        return "critical_attack"
    elif roll in range(101, 106):
        return "missed_attack"
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('This code should not be reached')

print(attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed())
```

It might help you understand what you are doing wrong. Note that this is a simple refactoring of your original code, I didn't really add anything new except the exception, but I rearranged the way your code was laid out in order to make it simpler for you to understand.

**Here is a more robust method:**

```
import random

def perform_attack(rand_max=105, normal=range(1,76), critical=range(76,101), missed=range(101,106)):
    roll = random.randrange(1, rand_max)
    outcomes = {'normal': normal, 'critical': critical, 'missed': missed}
    for outcome, field in outcomes.items():
        if roll in field:
            return outcome + '_attack'
    raise RuntimeError('Roll was outside of any specified range, check parameters')
```

**And here is a fool-proof method which can be adjusted *very* dynamically:**

```
import random

def attack(**attack_table):
    attack_table.setdefault('normal', 75)
    attack_table.setdefault('critical', 25)
    attack_table.setdefault('miss', 5)
    max_roll = 0
    outcomes = {}
    for outcome, chance in attack_table.items():
        outcomes[outcome] = range(max_roll, max_roll + chance)
        max_roll += chance
    roll = random.randrange(max_roll)
    for outcome, threat_range in outcomes.items():
        if roll in threat_range:
            return outcome
```

**Usage:**

The function automatically builds the threat ranges for each type of attack based on the chance number you assign it, by default there is normal, critical, and miss, all with the same chance as you had for them. if I were to assign a new type of outcome, say "super" with a chance of 500, then it would have a very likely chance of being the result:

```
>>> attack(super=500)
'super'
```

I can even change the chance of the miss to be greater:

```
>>> attack(miss=200)
'miss'
```

Or even remove the miss chance all-together:

```
>>> attack(miss=0)
'critical'  # lucky shot!
```

Comment: Your robust method scares me; where does the method .items come from?  i understand the robust method, just not all the ways you used to write it.

Comment: @bo2006 It is builtin, just like the `range` function.

Answer (score 3):

I would **strongly** advise you to refactor (aka completely change) your code:

Here's how I would start off:

```
def attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed():
    #Random number generated from a range
    import random
    number = random.randint(1, 105)
    print(number)
    print()

    if number < 76:
        return "normal_attack"
    elif 76 <= number < 101:
        return "critical_attack"

    # and so on

print(attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed())
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `number_list` contains only one integer. So "`if range1 in number_list`" will never be `true` and you will never return any string. Rather after checking all conditions it will return `None`.

Answer (score 1):

In essence you are getting `None` because you haven't specified a return if the conditionals fail (i.e. an else).

Your code is morally equivalent to

```
def attack_or_critical_attack_or_missed():
    if some_condition():
        return "something"
    #else
    #   implicitly return None
```

Why is this happening? You have replaced variables when you try to walk over them, e.g.

```
n = range(1, 76)
for n in n:
#  ... etc
```

You could avoid this by saying

```
for n in range(1, 76):
#  ... etc
```

though other answers have given much neater ways of changing the code. You also need to change the way you check if a specific number, rather than a list, is `in` another list.

Comment: the for n in range, has been giving me a hard time to conceptualize.  your example helps better.